# Program won't write to specified text file

Tags: python-3.x

The program I have to write is supposed to:

- prompt the user for a file name to write to.
- let the user specify how many random numbers will be generated and added to the file.
- Use random numbers in the range of 1 through 500.
- open the file to read and print after the program is done writing to the output file

However, when the program runs, it doesn't edit the text file I told it to. Because of this I can't achieve the last part of the requirements.

Here is my code:

```
import random

try:
    amt_nums = int(input("Enter the amount of random numbers you want: "))

except:
      print("Error: enter integer numbers only")

else:
    random_nums = open(input("Enter the file you want to open", 'w'))
    for i in range (amt_nums):
         num = random.randint(1,500)
         print(num)
         random_nums.write(str(num)+ '\n')
    random_nums.close()
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Do you see the file created? Is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in line `random_nums`, it should be:

```
random_nums = open(input("Enter the file you want to open"), 'w')
```

**w** it's a parameter to `open` method, not `input`.